# How not round up the value when adding or casting it to Money?

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
SELECT cast(cast(Ac.Amount as decimal(18,2)) as varchar)FROM Assessmentsurchargedetails AC
```

Result is:
5010.00
27.6
100.00
1000.00
10000.00

i just want to add comma separated when it hits a thousand.

Comment: Kindly share sample data and desired result

Comment: i have edited my question sir

Comment: pls. add some sample data as mentioned by @zarruq

Comment: The comma comes when you format the result. Numbers dont actually contain commas (in other cultures dots are used for example.) What version  of sql server, recent versions have the `format()` function?

Comment: yes it has. ive tried the format function but when im gonna convert it or cast it to decimal it has the error saying "Argument data type varchar is invalid for argument 1 of format function."

Comment: this the code i used to get that error: FORMAT(cast(cast(Ac.Amount as decimal(18,2)) as varchar),'##,##0')

Comment: Don't cast it to varchar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can accomplish this in three ways:

- Floor method
- Integer Conversion method
- Substring Method

Here are some examples

```
--Integer Conversion Method
    SELECT cast(cast(cast(Amount * 100 as int) / 100.0 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar) FROM Assessmentsurchargedetails AC
```

or

```
-- FLOOR Method
SELECT cast(cast(FLOOR(Ac.Amount*100)/100.0 as decimal(18,2)) as varchar) FROM Assessmentsurchargedetails AC
```

or

```
-- Substring Method, not the increased precision on the initial decimal cast
select LEFT(cast(cast(Ac.Amount as decimal(20,4)) as varchar), cast(LOG10(Amount) as int)+4) from Assessmentsurchargedetails ac
```

I decided to time each of the methods by inserting about 8.25 million rows from the original `Assessmentsurchargedetails` table to another table. The integer conversion method took 18 seconds to process, while the other two took 16 seconds. I would recommend the FLOOR method over the Substring method, however, because in most cases you will not want to cast the end result into a varchar, and it is a much more expressive way to solve the problem.

Regarding adding a comma, the commenters are correct- use FORMAT without casting to a varchar first. In that case, your final output would be:

```
SELECT FORMAT(cast(FLOOR(Ac.Amount*100)/100.0 as decimal(18,2)), '#,##0.00') FROM Assessmentsurchargedetails AC
```

Answer (score 0):

```
REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(20), (CAST(SUM(table.value) AS money)), 1), '.00', '')
```

use this **REPLACE** and **CONVERT** to get the desired results. 'varchar' doesn't support comma.